# Make WebView use a font present on the SD card

Tags: android, localization, fonts, android-webview

Android's Japanese font is horrible. The free **Mincho** font would be much better. Many people use our (open source) app to learn Japanese words, so we would like the app to download and use this font.

An existing free Android [app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/vertical-text-viewer/org.example.android.npn2SC1815J.VerticalTextViewer) is already doing it, but I have no idea how.

Downloading the font to the SD card is no problem, but how to make the WebView (or some spans within the WebView) use the downloaded font instead of the default font?

Comment: You could always try contacting the makers of the free app to ask how they're doing it. Maybe they aren't using WebView and have possibly written a native app instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to insert a CSS directive into the HTML sent to the WebView. This CSS directive references the font file via the "file:" protocol.

For an open source code sample and a more detailed explanation, see how we implemented it:
https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/commit/6225e524be4a77858e08389624d2f4ae8740261b

Answer (score 0):

WebView is used to load a web page inside a app.. Probably you got it wrong is my guess.
If you want to load external font into your app you can make use of the snippet

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets()
                    , "fonts/fontname.ttf");
```

and use them for any textview to display it in app.

Comment: The WebView component is not only for web pages. It is used in many applications to show rich text.